# Shape File Data Map to Osm Data For Routing

Tags: openstreetmap, shapefile

I am Working Routing application it is Basically Working on .osm File . I have shape file file so need to be changes used QGIS Desktop Application . But I have no idea Shape file Which Attributes map to OSM data Attributes

Comment: Which are your shapefile attributes exactly?

Comment: @scal i have geographical information in shape file example name,gid,alt_name,routename etc

Comment: Then you will have to look for corresponding [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) in OSM, for example the [name tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:name).

Comment: @scal but other tag like oneway how it is working

Comment: There is a [oneway tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:oneway), too.

Answer (score 0):

**Following Tag Used For OSM Data Routing**

**Way types**
highways

**Routing**
oneway,junction,maxspeed,bridge,tunnel,surface,access

**Relations**
type

**Directions**
lanes,name,name_1,ref

**Relations**
type